# Flex pass a string to another mxml always got the initial value of the public variable

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, public

I have a public variable sqlQuery in search.mxml which I want to use in searchResult.mxml, but it not work properly.

**Scenario 1**
  In my search.mxml

```
[Bindable] public static var sqlQuery:String;
In lower part of search.mxml, I set the value of sqlQuery
```

In my searchResult.mxml

```
Alert.show("query from other mxml = " + search.sqlQuery);
```

every time I got null value

**Scenaro 2**

If I assign a value to the definition of the public vaiable:

In my search.mxml

```
[Bindable] public static var sqlQuery:String = "ABC";
In lower part of search.mxml, I set the value of sqlQuery
```

In my searchResult.mxml

```
Alert.show("query from other mxml = " + search.sqlQuery);
```

every time I got value "ABC"

It seems I can only get the initial value of the varaible in another mxml, what is wrong with my code?

**EDIT**: The details for the search.mxml:

```
[Bindable] public static var sqlQuery:String;

        public function handleEvent():void
        {           

            sqlQuery = "SELECT ItemNo,ItemType,ItemName,Location FROM ITEM_DETAILS WHERE";

                if (ItemNo.text){  // BQ_NO has value
                    sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " ItemNo= '" + ItemNo.text + "'"
                }

                if (ItemType.text){
                        sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " and ItemType= '" + ItemType.text + "'"
                    }
                }

                if (ItemName.text){
                        sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " and ItemName = '" + ItemName.text + "'"
                }

                if (Location.text){
                        sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " and Location LIKE '%" + Location.text + "%'"
                }

                Alert.show("final sql Query = " + sqlQuery);   
                // this is what I need to pass to searchResult.mxml

            }
                var widgetId:Number = ViewerContainer.getInstance().widgetManager.getWidgetId("Search Result");  
                AppEvent.dispatch(AppEvent.WIDGET_RUN, widgetId); 

                this.setState("closed");    
        }
```

This is my searchResult.mxml which get the sqlQuery value in search.mxml:

```
import .search

public function init():void {

     Alert.show("query from search mxml = " + search.sqlQuery);
}
```

Comment: Post more of your code.  It's impossible to tell what's going on from the code snippets you've shown here :(

Comment: When is `searchResult.init()` called?  Make sure that doesn't happen until after you've run `search.handleEvent` class.  Also, for the code you've shown, `[Bindable]` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Brian, yes the searchResult.init() is called after search.handleEvent() ran. have updated the code.